# Oracle SQL - Subquery Works fine, However Create Table with that subquery appears to hang

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have the following query structure

```
CREATE TABLE <Table Name> AS 
(
   SELECT .... FROM ...
)
```

When i run the SELECT statement on its own, this compiles and returns the results within seconds. however when I run that with the CREATE Table Statement it takes hours to the point where I believe it has hung and will never compile.

What is the reason for this? and what could a work around be?

- Oracle Database 12c <12.1.0.2.0>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this one.

```
CREATE TABLE <Table Name> AS 
(
   SELECT foo 
   FROM baa
   LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT foo FROM baa WHERE DATES BETWEEN SYSDATE AND SYSDATE - 100 )
   WHERE DATES_1 BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE - 100
)
```

The problem was that the BETWEEN statements did not match the same time period and the sub query was looking at more data than the main query (I guess this was causing a full scan over the tables?)

The below query has the matching between statement time period and this returned the results in less than 3 minutes.

```
CREATE TABLE <Table Name> AS 
(
   SELECT foo FROM baa
   LEFT JOIN ( SELECT foo FROM baa WHERE DATES BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE - 100 )
   WHERE DATES_1 BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE - 100
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you ran that `SELECT` in some GUI, note that most (if not all) of them return only a few hundred rows, not the whole result set. For example: if your query really returns 20 million rows, GUI displays the first 50 (or 500, depending on tool you use) rows which is kind of confusing - just like it confused you.

If you used current query as an inline view, e.g.

```
select count(*)
from 
(select ... from ...)   --> this is your current query
```

it would "force" Oracle to fetch all rows, so you'd see how long it actually takes.

Apart from that, see if `SELECT` can be optimized, e.g.

- see whether columns used in `WHERE` clause are indexed
- collect statistics for all involved tables (used in the `FROM` clause)
- remove `ORDER BY` clause (if there's any; it is irrelevant in CTAS operation)
- check explain plan

Performance Tuning is far more from what I've suggested; those are just a few suggestions you might want to look at.

Comment: So the Inner Query has been designed around all the indexes of the joined and main table. I just counted all and its about 800k rows and returned this within a minute. I have looked at the explain plan previously, and nothing really sticks out with large costs (however my knowledge here isn't great) There is no order by clauses so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Direct Load insert by first creating the table  using CTAS where 1= 2and then doing the insert. This will atleast tell us if anything is wrong in data(corrupt data) or if it is a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before since the new data is too large (7 million rows) and it took me 3 hours to execute the code.

My best suggestion is to create a view since it took less space instead of a new table.